# spring form error tag: check for specific error (only display invalid if the not null is not present for example)

Tags: spring-mvc, java-ee-6, bean-validation

So I have a String I need to check for a valid format for which I used a pattern, and whether the entered value is valid according to some business rules for which I used a custom validator. Now the customer would prefer it if the error message associated with the latter is only shown if the former didn't occur. But as far as I know there is no way to make this distinction.
Or can anyone think of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is: have two different constraints (annotations),

- one for the pattern, that accept null,
- and a second for not null.

By default the `javax.validation.constraints.Pattern` "validator" accept null.

> Accepts String. `null` elements are considered valid.
>   (javax.validation.constraints.Pattern javadoc)

So what you need to do in the end is this:

```
@NotNull(message="{validation.notNull}")
@Pattern(pattern="123" message="{validation.notPattern}")
String myString;
```

---

**Added:**

(Comment)

> Not really the desired behaviour since I want to reuse the bean object but the conditions aren't the same for each page. – Jack Nickels 5 mins ago

In this case you can use the so called `groups` (See [JSR303 Bean Validation Spec, Chapter 4.1.2 groups](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/bean_validation-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/bean_validation-1_0-final-spec.pdf) -- there is also an example). Use the default Group for `@Pattern` and an other group for `@NotNull`. Now you can enable or disable the Validation rules according the groups you specify for validation.

```
validator.validate(myObject, Default.class);
validator.validate(myObject, MyGroup.class);
```

There is one problem left: in Spring 3.0 you can not Specify the Group you want to use for the automatic validation process. But in 3.1 you can, according to that Feature Request [SPR-6373](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6373) (I have not tryed it, but I hope it works)

Comment: Not really the desired behaviour since I want to reuse the bean object but the conditions aren't the same for each page.

Comment: @Jack Nickels: see my extended answer